# package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist

Tags: android, netbeans, actionbarsherlock

When I started using actionbarsherlock it worked just fine, but now when I open my project it doesn't seem to find the package ( "package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist" ), but it compiles and runs anyway. What could be causing this?
I am using NetBeans.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: @Michael Yes I have, no change.

Comment: What about trying to remove any dependencies, and then re-adding them?

Comment: I had the same problem and found a workaround, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724697/netbeans-doesnt-see-classes-from-referenced-library

Comment: Did your issue get fixed?

Comment: Where do you see the error message? Is it just in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check:

1. Verify your Android API, correct is (Google API 4.0)
2. Verify your Support Library is correct in your project n actionbarsherlock library, (Android Tools > Add suport library).
3. Verify your Compiler level, correct is 1.6.
4. Restart Java Compilter.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and I fixed it by adding

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

to the dependencies of SlidingMenu build.gradle