# Netbeans doesn't see classes from referenced library

Tags: java, android, netbeans, ide, actionbarsherlock

I'm using netbeans 7.2 with NBAndroid extension. In my android project, I'm referencing a library (ActionBarSherlock) that is not in jar (can't be, for some reason). The problem is, that netbeans doesn't see classes from that library and gives me errors (package does not exist etc.) However it builds and runs OK, the library is added correctly. Netbeans just doesn't see it.

Here is a [screenshot](http://oi50.tinypic.com/10fq9i0.jpg).

Here is similar question, no solution [package com.actionbarsherlock.app does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060208/package-com-actionbarsherlock-app-does-not-exist)

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks for help!

---

**EDIT:** So I found a way to solve this, it's more a workaround than a solution. I created a jar file from the library classes called classes.jar. I put it in the libs folder, so netbeans sees it. Than I created custom_rules.xml (it's imported via build.xml). In it I move classes.jar away from the libs folder, so I can build it, and in the end I move it back.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="imported">

    <copy file="libs/classes.jar" todir="./" />
    <delete file="libs/classes.jar" />

    <target name="-post-compile">
        <copy file="./classes.jar" todir="libs/" />
        <delete file="./classes.jar" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: what is your jar file folder name in the project?... i mean lib or libs

Answer (score -2):

The errors you see are because NetBeans doesn't recognize the packages, classes, methods, etc. When you build or run the program, NetBeans resorts to the Android project's Ant script, which apparently is configured correctly to find the classes. As far as compiling and running, you won't have a problem. However, if you want to use NetBeans' autocomplete and error-detection features, you need to configure it to detect your libs. To do this, just right click on your project name in the Project pane and click Properties from the context menu. Next, click on Libraries under Categories on the left. Then click Add JAR/Folder and navigate to the folder with your third-party library. You can select one of the options for the path then click OK. Now NetBeans should be able to find the identifiers and help you write your code.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is that there is a link to the library in project properties.

Comment: @Jaa-c Hrmm...is it a link to a library, project, or jar/folder?

Comment: Well, there are different properties for android project than for usual java project. In Libraries, there is a link to the folder with library sources, it's under referenced library projects.

Comment: @Jaa-c I know I installed that plugin, but it looks like it might have installed to the machine I was using at the time and not my USB drive where I have NetBeans installed. Now NetBeans doesn't even have the plugin listed. When I figure this out, I'll take a look and see what I can do to help.

Answer (score -2):

Rather than doing some tricks in your build script I'd recommend you to use ActionBarSherlock as a library project. You should be able to do this in project customizer (select project, right click, choose properties).

Also see 'Including in YOur Project' bullet 2. in http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

-Radim

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did and what causes the problem in netbeans.

Comment: Looking at your screenshot I think the problem is that your ACtionBarSherlock project is a Maven project. It is just simple Android library project in my case. Make sure it points to <relative_path>/ActionBarSherlock/library location. Maybe you also  need to remove pom.xml. Let me know if it helps.